# MediaRecorder crashes when record a second audio clip

Tags: android, eclipse, audio-recording, logcat

I am trying to record audio clips with MediaRecorder, but I keep getting these errors in my Logcat when I start, stop, and start again; the activity would also close:

```
INFO/DEBUG(1285): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
INFO/DEBUG(1285): Build fingerprint: 'LGE/thunderg/thunderg/thunderg:2.2.1/FRG83/eng.nikech.choi.20110126.134422:user/release-keys'
INFO/DEBUG(1285): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000010
INFO/DEBUG(1285):  r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 a930cc98  r3 00000001
……
INFO/DEBUG(1285):          #00  pc 00033c28  /system/lib/libmedia.so
INFO/DEBUG(1285):          #01  pc 0000780e  /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so
……
INFO/DEBUG(1285): code around pc:
INFO/DEBUG(1285): a9033c08 2001e001 1c1861a0 46c0bd70 00029a58 
……
INFO/DEBUG(1285): code around lr:
INFO/DEBUG(1285): a93077f0 f7ffb510 bd10ffcf b082b570 ae011c05 
……
INFO/DEBUG(1285): stack:
INFO/DEBUG(1285):     bef054d0  00000001 
……
```

An audio clip is recorded and can be played on the computer, but if I want to record another one, the above happens. I have already asked for permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
```

I used this code from Ben McCann:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;

/**
 * @author <a href="http://www.benmccann.com">Ben McCann</a>
 */

public class AudioRecorder {

  final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
  final String path;

  /**
   * Creates a new audio recording at the given path (relative to root of SD card).
   */
  public AudioRecorder(String path) {
    this.path = sanitizePath(path);
  }

  private String sanitizePath(String path) {
    if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
      path = "/" + path;
    }
    if (!path.contains(".")) {
      path += ".3gp";
    }
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path;
  }

  /**
   * Starts a new recording.
   */
  public void start() throws IOException {
    String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
        throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
    }

    // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
    File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
    if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
      throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
    }

    recorder.reset();
    System.out.println("reset");
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    System.out.println("setAudioSource");
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    System.out.println("setOutputFormat");
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    System.out.println("setAudioEncoder");
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    System.out.println("setOutputFile");
    recorder.prepare();
    System.out.println("prepare");
    recorder.start();
    System.out.println("start");
  }

  /**
   * Stops a recording that has been previously started.
   */
  public void stop() throws IOException {
    recorder.stop();
    System.out.println("stopped");
    recorder.release();
    System.out.println("released");
  }

}
```

My code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private final String TAG = TestActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    Button startRecord;
    Button stopRecord;
    boolean recordStarted = false;
    private static String fileName = "/Recordings/event.3gp";
    AudioRecorder audioRecorder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.record);

        startRecord = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStartRecord);
        stopRecord = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStopRecord);

        startRecord.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopRecord.setOnClickListener(this);
        audioRecorder = new AudioRecorder(fileName);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "resumed");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "paused");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == startRecord){
            try {
                audioRecorder.start();
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msgRecordSuccessful,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                recordStarted = true;
                Log.e(TAG, String.format("recording: %s", recordStarted));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msgRecordFail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if (v == stopRecord){
            if (recordStarted == true) {
                try {
                    audioRecorder.stop();
                    recordStarted = false;
                    Log.e(TAG, String.format("recording: %s", recordStarted));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msgNotRecording, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } // end onClick

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="start"
        android:id="@+id/buttonStartRecord"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonStopRecord"
        android:text="Stop"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Strings:

```
<string name="msgReset">reset</string>
<string name="msgSetAudioSource">setAudioSource</string>
<string name="msgSetOutputFormat">setOutputFormat</string>
<string name="msgSetAudioEncoder">setAudioEncoder</string>
<string name="msgSetOutputFile">setOutputFile</string>
<string name="msgPrepare">prepare</string>
<string name="msgStart">start</string>
```

I don't have a lot of programming experience and I have no idea what this means or how to even search for this problem in Google... if anybody can point me in a general direction that would be really nice :D

Thank you!!

------------ updates ---------------

@ Tim
the few lines after the debug block from logcat:

```
INFO/ActivityManager(1362): Process com.bcit.chairlogger (pid 26461) has died.
INFO/WindowManager(1362): WIN DEATH: Window{44f04e20 com.bcit.chairlogger/com.bcit.chairlogger.TestActivity paused=false}
INFO/ActivityManager(1362): Displayed activity com.bcit.chairlogger/.TestActivity: 106629 ms (total 106629 ms)
INFO/UsageStats(1362): Unexpected resume of com.lge.launcher while already resumed in com.bcit.chairlogger
WARN/Flex(1456): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE TLS
WARN/Flex(1456): getString FLEX_OPERATOR_CODE TLS
INFO/#LGIME(1442): #### onStartInput: restarting=false, fieldId=-1
WARN/InputManagerService(1362): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 26461 uid 10071
```

Comment: Is there some part of your Stack Trace that references what type of exception is thrown, and what line it was thrown by? What you have posted as your stack trace contains mostly what appear to be memory addresses which are not going to mean anything to anyone reading this. Look for something in the Cat Log that has the word Exception in it and post that portion.

Comment: yeah that's the part - NO EXCEPTIONS!!! so I am super confused and don't know what to search for

Comment: Ok I found this exception in orange (for Eclipse) after the above debug block: WARN/InputManagerService(1362): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 26461 uid 10071
Does this mean anything?

Comment: If you record 1 audio clip, then exit out of your application and re-start it. Then record another, does it break? Have you tried using a different filename the second time? Do you see any of your various println methods happening? If so what is the last one before it fails?

Comment: Post the next several lines of the log starting with the one you put in comment. But when you do it Edit your post instead of putting in comments, it'll get formatted and be easier to read.

Comment: If I close the application altogether (Settings, Applications, Manage, app, Force Stop) then start it, the old clip will be overwritten. The debug block also doesn't happen if I leave the application running for a while then resume it. I did see all the println methods the first time I press record, but none of them get triggered if I want to record a second clip (not even reset).
please refer to post for the additonal logcat lines.

Answer (score 2):

i had same error, solution that worked for me "And `MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();` at the beginning of start()" ([Several audio recording in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584217/several-audio-recording-in-android))

Comment: If that fixes the issue, then you might be leaking some internal components. You could start getting issues after a few more recordings.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by adding the recorder in stop functionality.

You need to add this 4 line code inside **stop()** then only you can start the second audio clip:

```
myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
```

**Refer below code:**

```
public void stop(View view) {
    try {
        myRecorder.stop();
        myRecorder.reset();
        myRecorder.release();

        stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
        playBtn.setEnabled(true);
        startBtn.setEnabled(true); 


        myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);


    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // it is called before start()
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // no valid audio/video data has been received
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was due to the AudioRecorder class. Since the new MediaRecorder object is created at the beginning of the class rather than in the "start" method, the object is released every time in the "stop" method, rendering it useless.

Comment: Yes, we are not allowed to call `mMediaRecorder.release();` ;)